# Some references including examples for good "Git commit messages"

Tags: git, version-control, commit, git-commit, conventional-commits

I need some references which include guidelines on having good git commit messages, its conventions and especially a few examples.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a definitive standard for git commit messages, but if anything is emerging to be one, it would be [Conventional Commits](https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0/).

With this convention, upgrading a dependency would probably be a `chore`, e.g.:

```
chore: Upgrade library XYZ to version 1.2.3

This upgrade solved CVE-2021-whatever discovered in the library.
If left unpatched, this vulnerability may allow attackers to bypass authentication in the
inventory update flow.
```

Comment: i agree but i wanted to know the most common ones and your answer did not help. anyway thanks!